# Android java InputStreamReader

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

I am trying to make an application that will allow me to issue commands in android and give me the results. This seems to be working fine with the exception that commands that wait a while for more output do not get processed correctly. I am trying to issue the command "su && nmap -sS 192.168.1.1" and all I get for output is that nmap has started. Does anyone know of a way to not only get the output that nmap has started, but the results of the scan using a modified version of the code below.

```
try {
        EditText inputTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
        String str = inputTxt.getText().toString();
        Process command = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(command.getInputStream()));
        int read;
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.append(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        reader.close();

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(output);

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Run_Command", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
```

Comment: May be `su` is just waiting for a password first?

Comment: You need to close the output stream that is the input to the process.

Answer (score -1):

I came up with another version of the code. This one uses thread.sleep and does not have a fixed size buffer.

Still all I get for output is that nmap has started, not the results of the scan even though the scan would have completed by the time the final thread.sleep was finished.

```
public void command(View view)
{
    String me;
    int a = 0;
    try {
        EditText inputTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
        String str = inputTxt.getText().toString();
        Process command = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str);

        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(command.getInputStream(), "UTF8"));
        //char [] me = new char[40960];
        String inputLine;
        while(1 == 1){
            if(a == 5) {
                break;}

        while ((inputLine = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            me += inputLine + "\n";
        }
            while(bReader.readLine() == null) {
                a++;
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                if (a == 5) {
                    break;
                }
            }
                    }
        bReader.close();

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(me);

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Run_Command", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pointless. Once `readLine()` has returned null, that's it. You can sleep from now until Doomsday but there will never be any more input.

Comment: There has to be a way to obtain the output, right? I may have been going about it in the wrong way?